# Do the words "Schlacht" und "schlecht" share the same root?

Tags: vocabulary

I am new to German. I came across these two words. I am curious to know if these two share same roots.

Comment: Your question implicitly contains a methodological problem: How do you define the term _root of a certain word_? There is no such thing as one single root, only a continuous history of ancestors. So, you should better ask: _How far can we date back the history of those two words and does the etymological research know common ancestors?_ I don't want to be picky here, I just want to point on this methodological issue for anyone reading this thread and not being aware of it.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach. “Root” (Würzel) is an established technical term in linguistics.

Comment: @fdb I know the term _root_ (_Wurzel_) in linguistics with a very different meaning, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_(linguistics) . Besides that, even if the term _Wurzel_ is an established term in etymology, I fail to recognize how this solves the methodological problem I described above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

---

### die Schlacht (engl: battle) (noun)

New High German (NHG) *»**Schlacht**«* was before (Middle High German = MHG) *»**slaht**«* and even before (Old High German = OHG) *»**slahta**«*. This OHG noun was derived from the OHG verb *»**slahan**«* which later became MHG *»**slahen**«* and now (NHG) is *»**schlagen**« (to strike, knock, punch, beat, hit, ...)*

But OHG *»**slahta**«* has an even older protogermanic root, and when both, English and German grew from this common root, this verb became *»**to slay**«* in modern English. So the German noun *»**die Schlacht**«* and the English verb *»**to slay**«* are relatives.

---

### schlecht (engl: bad) (adjective)

The NHG adjective *»**schlecht**«* was both, MHG and OHG *»**sleht**«* and is a sibling of the Old English word *»**sliht**«*, from which the modern English word *»**slight**«* derived. But it had a very different meaning in those days. It meant »flat, smooth«. The German verb *»**schleichen**«* (engl: *to creep, sidle, skulk, weasle, sneek, ...*) also derives from this root, also the German adjective *»**schlicht**«* (simple, plain).

Over many centuries this word changed its meaning:

flat & smooth → plain & simple → worthless → bad.

---

<sub>*Source:*</sub>
<sup>*DUDEN Das Herkunftswörterbuch (Duden Band 7) 3. Auflage, 2001, ISBN 3-411-04073-4*</sup>

Comment: Somebody gave this a downvote. Why? There could hardly be a more precise answer.

Comment: According to etymonline.com Old English *sliht* became *slight*, and *slick* has a different origin.

Comment: Aber Downvote heißt "The answer is not useful". Ein (kleiner) Fehler in der Herleitung, der noch nicht einmal am Kern etwas änder, macht eine ansonsten sehr gute Antwort doch nicht gleich nutzlos! Ein Kommentar mit dem Hinweis hätte als erster Schritt doch auch genügt.

Comment: I think, it is good practice to provide the sources of one's answer, especially when it is about etymology. Can you do so, Hubert? Anyway: Nice answer, especially the links to modern english words are very interesting!

Comment: Probably, the English *slaughter* and *onslaught* are related as well.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Das mit den Quellen halte ich für überbewertet. Ich habe keine wissenschaftliche Arbeit geschrieben, sondern eine Frage beantwortet. Wenn die Quelle eine Website ist, besteht die Gefahr, dass sie innerhalb weniger Monate/Jahre nicht mehr erreichbar ist. Wenn die Quelle bedrucktes Papier ist, wird sich hingegen kaum jemand die Mühe machen, die Quelle nachzuprüfen. ...

Comment: ... Doch davon mal abgesehen: Wer sagt denn, dass die Quelle recht hat? Ich habe meine Antwort aus dem Duden. Aber dort steht auch keine Quelle. Woher soll irgend jemand wissen, ob das, was dort steht richtig ist? Nur weil der Brockhausverlag das auf Papier druckt, muss es noch nicht richtig sein. Wie soll ich das nachprüfen? Wie soll ich nachprüfen, ob eine Quelle, die im Internet verfügbar ist, korrekt ist, wenn dort keine Quellenangabe steht? Und falls dort doch eine steht: Go to Start.

Comment: Hubert, der Sinn der Quellenangabe besteht nicht darin, dass Quellen automatisch recht haben, nur weil sie auf Papier gedruckt sind, sondern dass man damit die Qualität deiner Antwort besser einordnen kann. Natürlich ist der Duden kein Garant für absolute Richtigkeit. Aber es ist doch ein Unterschied, ob du dir die Antwort selbst ausgedacht hast, oder aber auf einem Zettel gelesen hast, den du vor der Bibliothek aufgelesen hast, oder aus dem Duden. Quellen gibt man an, um den eigenen Beitrag besser kritisierbar zu machen, nicht um sich gegen Kritik zu immunisieren.

Comment: Und zur Abgrenzung zur wissenschaftlichen Arbeit: Man gibt Quellen in wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten nicht deshalb an, weil es sich damit um wissenschaftliche Arbeit handelt (also zum Selbstzweck), sondern weil man erkannt hat, dass man das Wissensniveau des Diskurses damit heben kann. Und genau das streben wir hier in dem Forum ja auch an. Deswegen ist der Unterschied, den du da aufmachst ein rein äußerlicher.

Answer (score 2):

No. Those were separate on their vowel in Old High German already.

And there's also *schlicht* and *die Schlucht*, should you wonder. Also not related.

Comment: Right. So just to be on same page, they don't share same root.

Comment: Well, the adjectives *schlecht* and *schlicht* are in fact closely related. (See [my answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/47899/1487))

Comment: This leaves room for *Schlocht*, *Schlächt*, *Schlöcht*, *Schlücht*, *Schliecht* and *Schleucht* - all things that yet are to be discovered or invented. We have a bright future! Mind, however, that *schleicht* and *schlaucht* are already given.

Comment: Some sources: 

[1] Wolfgang Pfeifer: __schlagen__. In. ders.: __Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen__. Berlin Akademie Verlag 1989, https://www.dwds.de/wb/schlagen#et-1

[2] Pfeiffer: __Schlacht__. In: ebd., https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schlacht#et-1

[3] Pfeiffer: __schlecht__. In: ebd., https://www.dwds.de/wb/schlecht#et-1

[4] Pfeiffer: __schleichen__. In: ebd., https://www.dwds.de/wb/schleichen#et-1